# Disable Realm.Sync for Integration Tests

Tags: continuous-integration, realm, integration-testing

I made some integration test on my Realm, But when I run on my CI I'm getting this error message: `Realm.Sync is not available. Note that the developer edition of the Node.JS SDK for Realm does not include sync on Linux.`

I understood what message says, I don't need Realm Sync on my integration tests. How could I disable Realm.sync on CI environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well technically, `Realm.sync`*is* disabled on your CI -- as it's running on Linux. You could guard the parts of your code that relies on it with a condition of some sort to make sure you don't run code that accesses it on your CI machine.

Comment: Actually, I'm not using `Realm.sync` at all. Is there a way to initialize Realm object disabling all Sync behavior?